# Match dataframe rows one by one and return corresponding row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have two data frames `dfA`, `dfB`. `dfA` has two columns `value` and `action`, and `dfB` has one column `action`. I want to match the B with A on 'Value' column and return the 'Action' item, if not it will return the string "NOT MATCHED".

`dfA`:

```
value          action
"user"           "enter"
"password"       "enter"
"login"          "click"
"customerid"     "enter"
"phonenumber"    "enter"
"submit"         "click"
```

`dfB`:

```
 value
 "submit"
 "password"
 "sign in"
 "cutomerid"
 "phonenumber"
 "user"
```

I want my output dataframe to look like this:

`dfB`:

```
 value             action
 "submit"          click
 "password"        enter
 "sign in"         notmatched
 "cutomerid"        enter
 "phonenumber"      enter
 "user"             enter
```

Comment: This is just a pandas [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (LEFT-JOIN), followed by a [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). Duplicate of [pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Comment: Please tag pandas question as [tag:pandas] as well as [tag:python]. It helps the get seen and answered faster.

Comment: The mispelling of 'customerid'/'cutomerid' will cause a no-match on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas merge functionality and left join desired output can be
achieved.
While using merge() first two arguments are the dataframes that we want to merge, 3rd argument is to merge on which column so there "value" is specified, as 4th argument "left" is passed which denotes that both the dataframe should be merged using left join.

Left join: Left join operation provides all the rows from 1st dataframe and matching rows from the 2nd dataframe. If the rows are not matched in the 2nd dataframe then they will be replaced by NaN.

At last NaN values are replaced with string "notmatched" as to achieve desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
value = ["user","password","login","customerid","phonenumber","submit"]
action = ["enter","enter","click","enter","enter","click"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(value,action)))
df1.columns = ["value","action"]
# print(df1)

value = ["submit","password","sign in","cutomerid","phonenumber","user"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(value)
df2.columns = ["value"]
# print(df2)

df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1,on="value",how="left")
df3["action"] = df3["action"].fillna("notmatched")
print(df3)
```

Edit :
As OP has asked question in a comment, below can be used to print :

```
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    if (row["action"]=="notmatched"):
        print("not match")
    else:
        print(row["action"])
```

Comment: what if i pass inside the loop, i mean,  if B value matches the A value, print("enter") and do some operations, if B values not matches , print("not match") and skip

Comment: @Soumya_jeet so you don't want a separate dataframe as output, because this matches completely with your desired output as mentioned in question

Comment: @Soumya_jeet in case if you want to print then iterate through the dataframe only.

Comment: @Soumya_jeet please check, I have updated answer that does printing based on matching value.

Comment: its not only need to print enter ,  click also there.

Comment: @Soumya_jeet updated the answer to print enter/click. Please check

Comment: This was a straight-up duplicate of a well-known question with 700+ upvotes. Please just vote-to-close on duplicates, they'll get closed pretty fast so answering them won't earn rep.